# How to test upload file and json in same request with postman?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm working on an C# MVC Web Api project. I have a controller defined as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveImage(Image imageInfo)
{
}
```

I am using MultipartMemoryStreamProvider for extracting the file as an array of bytes.

I wish to test this request, but I don't know how to configure postman for sending both file and json. I keep getting:

"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."

Could you tell me how to configure postman to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files, you can't have a parameter in the SaveImage method.  See this for an example:  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2